# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when configuring UITableView

Tags: swift

I have the error: **unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** in my project. Can you help me to understand what is the problem?

Here a link to my file: http://d.pr/f/1bn1l

Comment: Hi, downloaded and ran your project, but working fine without any issue which you mentioned....

Comment: can you tell specifically, which action in your project generate that error??

Comment: You should post relevant snippets of your code and not a link to the whole project.

Comment: why do you say this vacawama?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I finded the problem. I solved with the deleting of derived data's content in xcode folder and with the deleting of the app by the simulator. Thank you for your help and availability.